# YugabyteDB YCQL transaction capabilities

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I'm trying to figure out how powerful YCQL transactions are. Reading https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/explore/transactions/distributed-transactions-ysql/#execute-a-transaction I can see that I can update multiple tables in the transaction, so I can keep them consistent. But I struggle to figure out how can I read them to see a snapshot. Also is there a way to run read-modify-write type of transactions with YCQL?

Answer (score 0):

There are no client-controlled transactions in YCQL like in YSQL. YCQL transactions work like YSQL with autocommit on.

The reason is that YCQL was developed to match Cassandra’s API, but also be consistent. For more features like client controlled transactions, triggers, procedures you should use the YSQL layer.